# Select ComboBox Value and Put them in Corresponding Textboxes

Tags: excel, vba

I'm quite new to VBA so I am quite confuse on accessing a ComboBox's row value. So I have this ComboBox that show names from a column starting at E4 to the last name in a column. However, I have multiple textboxes that are tied to specific cells and they are correlated to that name, for example, [this row here has an example name 'Paul Kim'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0IbYu.png) and I want to access that resource name and make it appear to the corresponding text boxes [I have in my userform.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6CFLD.png) This is my code so far:

```
Private Sub ComboBox2_Enter()

currWrkSheet = ComboBox1.Value


If currWrkSheet = "Select a Project" Then
    MsgBox ("Select a Project")
    Exit Sub
End If


Worksheets(currWrkSheet).Activate

ComboBox2.List = Worksheets(currWrkSheet).Range("E4", Range("E4").End(xlDown)).Value

'Once getting the value of the combobox, it should show the values from the corresponding texboxes/comboboxes

'ComboBox2.ListRows    
End Sub
```

I don't really have an idea on how get combobox's row value and implement it because the solutions for this are all over the place and quite confusing to understand so I can put them in. The only thing I can get to is the ListRows method but I am still quite confuse on how to use it. Any clue how I can do this or approach it?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? `ListRows` only specifies the maximum number of rows to display in the list. `ComboBox2.List(0, 0)` Should give you "Paul Kim". `ComboBox2.ListCount` returns the number of entries.

Comment: I make lot of such projects for my client. Here is how I usually do it. **1.** Populate only the combobox which has the Project name in the `UserForm_Initialize()` event. **2.** Set the `Style` property of this combobox to `fmStyleDropDownList` **3.** When user selects a value from the above combobox then In the `ComboBox_Click()` event, use `rng.Find` to [find](http://www.siddharthrout.com/index.php/2018/01/05/find-and-findnext-in-excel-vba/) the cell value in the relevant sheet and then populate the textboxes based on the found row.

Comment: @ChristoferWeber I already am populating my ComboBox from a specific column using "ComboBox2.List = Worksheets(currWrkSheet).Range("E4", Range("E4").End(xlDown)).Value" and what I am trying to do is when I select Paul Kim, I want to populate my userform's textboxes associated with that name's row like Paul Kim's hours during that month.

Comment: You can read the `ListIndex` property of the Combobox to get the item picked. This value + 4 would be the row that you will want information from. Then just pick the appropriate column for each textbox. Maybe do this with the `ComboBox2_Change()` event. Like `Functiontxtbx.value = Worksheets(1).Cells(ComboBox2.ListIndex + 4, 3).value` Or just search the `ComboBox2.value` selected with `range.Find` like Siddharth said.